# Android - Navigation Drawer and NavigationBar

Tags: android

i implemented a navigation bar at the bottom of my activity
now i need to implement a navigationdrawer too
how do i do?

here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.movemate.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/transparent">
    </FrameLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        design:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        design:itemIconTint="@color/White"
        design:itemTextColor="@color/White"
        design:itemBackground="@drawable/navigation_selected_item"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

i tried with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtOztjHmM0c 
but when i compile it says i already have a navigation bar

EDIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="app.movemate.MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    layout="@layout/navigation_view"/>


            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
                android:layout_gravity="start"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            design:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            design:itemIconTint="@color/White"
            design:itemTextColor="@color/White"
            design:itemBackground="@drawable/navigation_selected_item"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

i tried this and i can see the navbar at bottom but the fragment is covered by drawer background
suggestions?

EDIT - SOLVED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.movemate.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/navigation_view"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/navigationView"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            design:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            design:itemIconTint="@color/White"
            design:itemTextColor="@color/White"
            design:itemBackground="@drawable/navigation_selected_item"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        design:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create navigation drawer u should use drawerLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: yes,In the frame layout whatever you want in the home page u can create here.

Answer (score 0):

in android studio, Navigation bar and navigation layout automatically gets added once you create a new activity from templates "navigation drawer activity"

Comment: just add drawer layout as @sarvan suggested and do the handeling accordingly in your linked activity to that xml